# datagridview cell accepts only numbers and some special character

Tags: regex, vb.net, string-function

My requirement is to allow only numbers,`.`,`<`,`-` and `<` in certain columns on my datagridview.The example inputs are `2.5`,`1-15.5`,`>10`,`>12.54`,`<75` etc

I'm using regex to check the pattern matching following is my code

```
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(val, "^[\d.-]+$") Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

But this accepts only numbers,`.` and `-` that means which return true if I pass `val="2.5"` or `val="5-10"`

So my question is how to make it for other symbols(`>`,`<`)

Comment: Just put these symbols in the square brackets.

Comment: When you tried, you must have misplaced `-` and it created a range. But I am guessing now, since you really have not added that to the question. It is unclear as it is now. You must always include what you have done, and why/how it failed for you. Adding `<` and `>` is trivial: `"^[<>\d.-]+$"`.

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, you said it. Mistake was mine and `"^[<>\d.-]+$"` is working

Comment: @stribizhev how can I handle white spaces ??

Comment: Do you want to also allow all whitespace or only *horizontal* whitespace? No linebreaks?

Comment: @stribizhev this is an example - `val="5 - 10"`

Comment: Are all numbers non-negative?

Comment: @SebastianProske Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a structural check and be space relaxed you may use something like this:

```
^(\s*(?:[-><])?\s*\d+(?:[.]\d+)?)+$
```

Try the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS5eX4/3).

This accept also: `1.5 - 10.3` or `< 10` but refuse invalid `< 10.2.` or `1 - ..` accepted before.

**Update**
To accept only single number disequality (accept `< 10.2` but refuse `>10 <5`) and accept at max `2` operands in subtractions (accept `1.2 - 3.4` but refuse `1 -1 - 1`)  (as stated by @SebastianProske):

```
^(\s*[><]\s*\d+([.]\d+)?|\d+([.]\d+)?\s*(-?\s*\d+([.]\d+)?\s*)?)$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tS5eX4/5)

*PS*: to be more precise we can replace all the `\s` with `[ \t]` to not accept newlines and other whitespace chars.

Comment: This one is perfect for my requirement

Comment: Why use the first non-capturing group around single subpattern? Use `^(\s*[-><]?\s*\d+(\.\d+)?)+$` with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture`. The same functionality, but shorter. To only match horizonatal whitespace, replace `\s` with `\p{Zs}`.

Comment: @stribizhev: i'm methodical so if i don't extract them i put always the non capturing sequence ``?:`` but you're right for readability in this case it' better be remove them.

Comment: This matches `>1>1` as well as `1-1-1`

Comment: @SebastianProske: i've added an update in addiction to the first version to exclude these cases too, more bounds leads to a more complex regex of course)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like:

```
If System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(val, "^\s*?[<>]?\d+?\s*?[\-]?\s*?\d+?[.]?\s*?\d+?$") Then
   Return True
Else
   Return False
End If
```

In this way you optionally match for < and > at the beginning of the string.

EDIT: With the fix now spaces are considered. Using this regex strings like 1-1-1 or 2.2. aren't matched.

Comment: You do not need to escape `<` and `>`.

Comment: Are you sure? I usually escape special characters if I'm not sure of that. :)

Comment: Almost there but what if `val="5 - 10"`(_to handle that space_)?

Comment: Oh, you're right. Sorry, I saw no spaces in the example so didn't think about that. I'll edit my answer in order to consider spaces.

Comment: @LucaMus your's also working its my bad not to mention whitespace,+1

Comment: Look at the edit, I also checked for string with multiple "-" or "."

Answer (score 0):

Not responsive to the "RegEx" question but a suggested alternate. I've found RegEx to be a big time waster (developing, CPU cycles, and maintenance.) Here is a string encoder from an OAuth sample that could easily be modified to do what you want using a simple string as the list of allowed characters.

```
    Protected Function UrlEncode(ByVal value As String) As String
        Dim result As New StringBuilder()
        For Each symbol As Char In value
            If unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) <> -1 Then ' "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_.~"
                result.Append(symbol)
            Else
                result.Append("%" + String.Format("{0:X2}", Convert.ToInt32(symbol)))
            End If
        Next
        Return result.ToString()
```